# Build shared lib in osx (.so)

Tags: c, macos, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "defs.h"
struct polynome saisie(void);
struct polynome mult (struct polynome, struct polynome);

/* ************************************************
   produit 
   Produit de 2 polynomes saisis au sein de la fonction
   entree : -
   sortie : -
**************************************************** */
void produit(void) {
   struct polynome P1,P2,Q;
   int i;
   printf("Premier polynome : \n");
   P1=saisie();
   printf("Second polynome : \n");
   P2=saisie();
   Q=mult(P1,P2);
   for(i=Q.degre; i>=0; i--)
      printf("coefficient de X a la puissance %d : %d\n",i, Q.coef[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
```

With this command :

```
gcc -shared -o lib/libop.so lib/*.o
```

And I always get this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_saisie", referenced from:
  _produit in produit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I dont know if it might help you but there's my gcc -v output :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

EDIT : Here is the header included

```
#define N   10

struct polynome {
    int degre;
    int coef[N];
};
```

In addition, i'll say that some of my coworkers compiled this code into a shared library successfully on linux machines. Maybe the problem resides in my configuration ? But I can't see where

Comment: perhaps your header might be useful too.

Comment: I don't see the definition of this function: `struct polynome saisie(void);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared these functions:

```
struct polynome saisie(void);
struct polynome mult (struct polynome, struct polynome);
```

**But you have not implemented them**.

Also copying the `struct`s, rather than passing pointers to them, looks a bit inefficient as they are not trivial in size, so I would have implemented those methods with these semantics:

```
void saisie(struct polynome *out);
void mult(const struct polynome *in1, const struct polynome *in2, struct polynome *out);
```

Possibly returning some status if it makes sense.  Also the name `mult()` looks like the root cause of a *duplicate symbol linker error* in the future...

Also also OS X uses the `.dylib` file extension, not `.so`, for dynamic objects.

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution. Do you know why my coworkers have built the library successfully without modifying the code like I did ? (i think they were working on ubuntu, is gcc more permissive than clang ?)

Comment: @Eschard1991 They must have included another source/object file that you have not (one including the implementation).